# Server side export to excel in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

We have a HTML page containing the HTML table which is populated dynamically with content from server. The requirement is to able to export the HTML table to excel in IE as well as Firefox.

We are trying following approach -

1. The HTML table is first being sent to the server with the content as a POST request using XHR.
2. at the server side there is HttpServlet  which is sending the content back with MIME type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" as a repsonse to the POST request.
3. At the browser the status of request is monitored and is observed as 200. However we are not getting any prompt from browser for opening the excel.

Appreciate if someone can help with this and throw some light on what we are missing on.

Thanks,
Adish

Comment: Try playing with the Content-Disposition header

Answer (score 0):

You have to use form submit instead of XHR if you want a single one POST request to handle that.

If you want to use ajax. The excel file needs to be cached or persisted somewhere. The server returns the url for the excel file in response of xhr post. Then in the success callback use window.open(url) to GET the file, which will prompt for downloading. This will use two requests.

I am not sure if iframe can work around.